# I cannot found Batch Drawable Importer Plugin in Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: java, android-studio, plugins, installation

Is this plugin unavailable now or this plugin changes the name? How can I fix this problem.

Comment: It is available as I Installed it but its not working since I have updated Android Studio to 3.6

Comment: Ok. thank you all. I got my answer.